# UpdatePanel causing full postback. Trying to do a partial postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am working on a page that is using a gridview to display data. I have some dynamically created textboxes inside an ItemTemplate which contains several textboxes per row. Now I also have an update panel that is using ajax and should only render once my link button is clicked. The datalist is bound in my code behind after the  I would like this to occur without causing a full postback. However, right now when I click the link button it causes a full post-back which eliminates my dynamically created controls.

I feel I am very close to a solution. I need one of these to happen (option 1 seems more useful):
Do not cause a postback when the linkbutton is clicked, but still render my full datalist in the update panel

or

my dynamically created controls are not removed during post back.

Here is my code:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
        [&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="SelectCommand" CommandName="Select"  runat="server" Text="+" CssClass="sunocoBold"/>&nbsp;]
        <%-- start sub panel--%>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"> 
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
             OnItemCommand="DataList_OnItemCommand"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Select" CommandName="SelectCommand" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ship_to_num")%>'  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ship_to_num")%>'  />
             </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:DataList> 

        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel> 
        <%-- end sub panel--%>
    </ItemTemplate>



  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site Owner"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlNames" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
      <%-- <asp:Literal ID="NameList" runat="server" /> --%>
    </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

UpdatePanel.Triggers is made for this!

Take a look at it here: [Understanding UpdatePanel.Triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer instead of just a link?

Comment: downvote given because there is no explanation given for the question. Instead of providing link, need some more straight forward explanation.